# QML/JS/REST Authentication form

Tags: javascript, rest, qml

I am making a registration + login form in QML + JS with REST API but since it's my first project with QML I am stuck on how to pass input values to use in javascript functions. Here's the code for the whole form so far.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 768
title: qsTr("Hello World")

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Rectangle {
        id: emailRec
        x: 195
        y: 180
        width: 255
        height: 40
        color: "#ffffff"
        border.color: "#333333"
        border.width: 1

        MouseArea {
            id: emailMouseArea
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 255
            height: 40
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: passRec
        x: 195
        y: 302
        width: 255
        height: 40
        color: "#ffffff"
        border.color: "#333333"
        border.width: 1

        MouseArea {
            id: passMouseArea
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 255
            height: 40
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: emailLabel
        x: 195
        y: 149
        text: qsTr("Email")
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pixelSize: 21
    }

    Text {
        id: passLabel
        x: 195
        y: 271
        text: qsTr("Password")
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pixelSize: 21
    }

    TextInput {
        id: emailInput
        x: 205
        y: 185
        width: 230
        height: 29
        text: ""
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pixelSize: 21
        selectByMouse: true
        editingFinished: {

        }

    }
    TextInput {
        id: passInput
        x: 205
        y: 308
        width: 230
        height: 29
        text: ""
        font.pixelSize: 21
        selectByMouse: true
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: submitBtnRec
        x: 195
        y: 385
        width: 255
        height: 40
        color: "#ffffff"

        MouseArea {
            id: submitMouseArea
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 255
            height: 40
            onClicked: {

            }
        }
    }
    Text {
        id: submitLabel
        x: 279
        y: 393
        text: qsTr("SUBMIT")
        font.family: "Verdana"
        font.pixelSize: 21
    }

}


Text {
    y: 58
    text: "uniqCast"
    font.bold: true
    font.family: "Verdana"
    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 1
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    color: "#2ecc71"
    font.pixelSize: 28
}

MessageDialog {
    id: messageDialog
    title: qsTr("May I have your attention, please?")

    function show(caption) {
        messageDialog.text = caption;
        messageDialog.open();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `var email = emailInput.text` ?

Comment: @KonstantinT. Where do I put that? editingFinished in the TextInput? If i do that I get "cannot assign to non-existent property "editingFinished"

Comment: Why don't you start from the beginning? Learn QML/JS, run examples, looks through tutorials and so start some project. [This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-codesamples.html) is good point to start.

Comment: `editingFinished` is a signal, so you react to that by using `onEditingFinished`.
Same principle you already have used for reacting to the `MouseArea`'s `clicked` signal by using `onClicked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in *click handler* of your submit button.

**Example:**

```
Rectangle {
        id: submitBtnRec
        .....
        MouseArea {
            id: submitMouseArea
            .....
            onClicked: {
                 var email = emailInput.text
                 var password = passInput.text
                 your_api.login(email,password)
            }
        }
    }
```